# CCTableView action on cell button stop working after scroll

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem with CCTableView. I give an action on the cell.button and it works but, after scrolling a bit, the action is no more fired.

I use

```
[cell.button setTarget:self selector:@selector(onMyButtonClicked:)];
```

Anyone has an idear on this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I forgot to put [super onEnter]; in the onEnter function.

Now everything is fine.